# auto schedule upload using batch file and command prompt

Tags: batch-file, file-upload, cmd, web

I am trying to use a cmd file to run a batch file that uploads a file of mine to a directory of my website. The batch file looks like this:

```
    open ip address
    username
    password
    option confirm off
    cd \public_html\wp-content\uploads\2014\07
    put "C:\Users\a\Documents\pdf\Contact Info.pdf"
    quit
```

The cmd file looks like this:

```
    ftp -s:c:\Users\a\Documents\upload.bat
```

When I run the cmd file I get output in command prompt that says that my username and password are ok and then tells me that option confirm off is an invalid command and that the cd filepath is a prohibited file name. It then says my file is uploaded but I can't find where the file is put. Is  there a reason why this is happening? Is it possible to upload the file to that directory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `winscp`. Download: http://winscp.net/eng/download.php

`option confirm off` is a valid WinSCP command, see http://winscp.net/eng/docs/scriptcommand_option

**Example: Uploading a single file with WinSCP**

http://winscp.net/eng/docs/script_upload_single_file

**Step 1**

create file: winscp-upload-script.txt

```
option batch abort
option confirm off
open sftp://username:password@example.com/
put "C:\Users\a\Documents\pdf\Contact Info.pdf" \public_html\wp-content\uploads\2014\07
exit
```

**Step 2**

create file: do-upload.bat

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP\winscp.com" /script=winscp-upload-script.txt
```

**Step 3**

Go scheduler, create new task, like described here (http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/12444-task-scheduler-create-new-task.html) and use `do-upload.bat` and configure event timing.

-Done-

Comment: the reason im using a batch file is i want to be able to use windows task manager to schedule this file to be run daily, and i can't do that with winscp

Comment: i want you to write what?

Comment: I've added simple steps, which describe how you do it. You can do it with WinSCP.

Comment: ok so I created the files you have there, but where is the scheduler in winscp? I can't find it. And thank you very much for your help!

Comment: winscp comes into play for the file transfer. the script files might be executed manually on the command line for testing, e.g. to make sure that login is correct and file is uploaded. if that works, you might add them to the task scheduler for repeated, event based execution.

Comment: Task Scheduler is in Windows. WinSCP is your file transfer tool. Scripts are the glue between them.

Comment: right now when I run the do-upload.bat file, command promp says: C:\Users\a\Documents>winscp.com/script=winscp-upload-script.txt 'winscp.com' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Comment: You don't have it installed, i guess. Fetch it from http://winscp.net/eng/download.php

Comment: i do have it installed

Comment: Then put the full path to winscp.com into the do-upload.bat file, like  c:\somewhereOnYourDisk\winscp\winscp.com - so that the file is found, when the batch gets executed.

Comment: like this?    cd "C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP"
cd "C:\Users\a\Documents"
winscp.com /script=winscp-upload-script.txt
pause

Comment: I've updated step 2 with your path. It must be in quotes, because of the space in the folder name. the cd into the documents folder is not necessary, it's already in step 1 .. see put

Comment: ok i made those changes but now in the command prompt it says: C:\Users\a\Documents>"C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP\winscp.com" /script=winscp-upload-script.txt batch     abort    confirm    off   prompting for credentials... username:        authentication failed

Comment: we need to get the login working now. you might alter the line with sftp://user:password@example.com/ to your login credentials - and maybe the hostkey directive is needed for the first login.

Comment: right now rather than using the website url I'm using its direct ip address, and providing the username and password directly below it like this:  open ftp:ip address
(next line)username
(next line)password                  would that cause the problem?

Comment: that is not a valid syntax for winscp. see http://winscp.net/eng/docs/scriptcommand_open so please add the credentials to the open command. (you can always exchange a domain name with it's ip adress. no problem.)

Comment: ok so now in the command promt the session starts and it seems to think its uploading the file but when i look for it on the server I can't find it anywhere

Comment: hmm - maybe the file transfer must be in passive mode. just guessing, but let's try that: open sftp://username:password@example.com/ -passive=on

Comment: i added the -passive=on but the file still didnt show up, again thank you for helping so much with this

Comment: do you have access to your ftp.log on the server? that would bring some light into this. if not: i think we have the login right, next questions are silly, but: does the file you want to upload exist and did you look in the right upload folder? does the upload folder exist? do you have permission to upload into that folder? if not, you have to change the folder permissions (chmod). do a test upload with target folder "\public_html" to just test uploading

Comment: when i try uploading to "\public_html" it fails and says can't upload to a directory. and i also can't find any ftp log on my godaddy hosting. the upload folder does exist but I'm not sure if i have permission to upload there, is there a way to check that?

Comment: as a customer of godaddy, you might ask them for support. guess, now it's time. they might also have a support forum.